# Missing Artifact in Maven Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to follow a MapR/Hadoop tutorial and when I reference this dependency it says missing artifact. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FirstHadoopProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstHadoopProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-mapr-2.1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It highlights depency and says: Missing artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.0.3-mapr-2.1.2.1

The tutorial doesn't specify what to do if that happens :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.0.3-mapr-2.1.2.1` is not a valid version in the central repository.  Try updating the dependency to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

or better yet, if the example will still compile, the latest version of `hadoop-core`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

You can check the version via the central repo:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hadoop-core%22

Comment: okay nice that fixed it. How/where did you check to notice that?

Comment: @sreya - I checked it at search.maven.org (added link above).  Glad I could help.  Don't forget to accept if the answer was helpful and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Notice that is also possible to download the latest version of an artifact using <version>LATEST</version>

Comment: is that the best way to specify version, generally?

Comment: Yeah I was going to accept it but I have to wait the initial five minutes

Comment: @Diego Pino - Yes, that is possible as well.  I tend to like to keep my version numbers explicit though as I don't like things changing without me knowing about it.

Comment: No it's not generally best way to specify version.  During normal development, it's unlikely you will want to change versions without explicitly indicating so.  However, if you are just exploring a new technology, then you definitely want the latest.

Comment: Yes sure, generally is best to put it explicit so you know what you are getting. But for cases like this, when it seems a version number is not working, some times what I do is to put LATEST, see what maven downloads and then make it explicit.